# personalize webpart-problem in giving url to xml file in toolpart

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am creatng a webpart and I am tryng to reference xml from toolpart . I hv created custom properties and its fine if I set the default value to some url otherwise its showing msg fle not found. I want that if its the first time I am loading file it should display the message Open tool part to select the XML.

I m doing lke ths:

```
private string feedXML;
        [Browsable(true),
        Personalizable(true),
         Category("Example Web Parts"),
         DefaultValue(""),
         WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared),
         FriendlyName("MySetting"),
         Description("An example setting")]

        public string FeedXML
        {
            get
            { return feedXML; }

            set
            { feedXML = value; }
        }
string xmlurl = String.Empty;
                string _xsl = string.Empty;
                // Load the XML

                xmlurl = web.GetFileAsString(GetRelativeURL(feedXML));<---exception as feedXML is null

                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

                doc.LoadXml(xmlurl);
```

As the frst time webpart is loadng its quite obvious it wud be feedXML wud be null but I want to display the msg to user "Select XML frm toolpart" as we generally get when we add OOB webpart (like XML Webpart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `CreateChildControls` method; if `feedXML` is null, create a label that says *Open tool pane ...* and add it to Web Part's `Control` collection.

Also, check the [Creating a Web Part with a Custom Tool Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584178(office.11).aspx) article.

Comment: yah thats the thng even if I check it like 

If(feedXML!=null) then proceed but the point is in that case  want to show user message to open tool part....Any idea on that?

Comment: I can also define some default value to it but I want the user to show msg to select xml from toolpart